# Laravel - Arranging images in ascending and descending order with links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a create method in my controller

```
public function create()
{
    $image = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    foreach($image as $property)
    {
        $id = $property->property_id;
    }
    $image_main = Image::where('property_id', $id)->get();
    return view('settings.photos', ['image_array' => $image_main]);
}
```

This is my blade view

```
<form name="asc" action="{{route("settings.photos")}}" method="post" class="text-center">
        @csrf
        <input type="submit"  value="Ascending " class="settings-photos-header2 text-center"/>  |
    </form><form name="dec" action="{{route("settings.photos")}}" method="post"  class="text-center">
        @csrf
        <input type="submit"  value= " Descending" class="settings-photos-header2 text-center"/>
    </form>
    <h2 class="settings-photos-header2 text-center">Photo Gallery</h2>
    @foreach ($image_array as $images)
        <div class="image-warp"><img src="{{$images->filename}}"
                                     style="width:100px;height:100px;"><br/><span style="color: #1b1e21">{{$images->description}}</span>
        </form>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

Question-
How can i make the asc button sort the images in ascending order and des in descending order, is there a way to connect it to my controller, or is there a way to sort them in ascending and descending order through `<a href>` links?

Comment: What do you mean by ascending and descending order? I don't even see an input field for the form.

Comment: It doesn't have to be forms, it can be an <a href> link, as far as the button/link sorts the images in a particular order

Answer (score 0):

First, `foreach` overrides `$id` in each iteration, so finally value of `$id` is `$property_id` value of last item from `$image` array.

You need to define relations.

In `PropertyUser` class add:

```php
public function images() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Image::class, 'property_id');
}
```

Then, in your `create` method in controller:

```php
public function create(Request $request) {    

  // use direction query parameter to define asc or desc sorting
  $order_direction = $request->query('direction');

  $property_user = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                                 ->with(['images' => function($query) use ($order_direction) {
                                     $query->orderBy('id', $order_direction)                                     
                                 })->get();

  // here you can access an array with associated images:
  $images = $property_user->images;  

  return view('settings.photos', ['image_array' => $images]);
}
```

Your link to sorted images should like: `<a href="/create.html?direction=asc">Sort asc</a>`